# linking native library libxml2 into xamarin.ios project with binding project

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, libxml2, objective-sharpie

I have an xcode code that uses the library libxml2.tbd  I needed to make that code a static library (myProjectLib.a) that can be used inside Xamarin.ios following this official guidelines:
[Binding iOS Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/)

The problem is that I get alot of errors about undefined symbols while building the xamarin project as if the project can't link libxml2

> Error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _xmlTextWriterFlush. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in

I did this binding successfully several times but only without dependency library. but there must be a solution to link it.

things that  I already tried :
-adding libxml2.dylib into the xcode library project (same error in xamarin)
-adding (-libxml2,-lxml2) into other linker flags in xcode library project (same error in xamarin)
-adding the libxml2.dylib file into xamarin binding project, xamarin app project resources with always copy options (same error in xamarin)

last tried:
-adding --gcc_flags="-stdlib=libxml2"  into (Additional mtouch arguements) in xamarin app project, gave another error that the name is not valid

> Error MT5209: Native linking error: clang: error: invalid library name in argument '-stdlib=libxml2'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `-lxml2` to linker flags in the properties of the native library that is added as a native reference in the iOS binding project. [It should look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk2Im.png)

Comment: yep worked like a charm! your photo showed me my mistake also , I was adding the native library as "Add a file" which I realized its deprecated, the right way which will result your the properties of your photo is adding the library inside (Native References) folder.. Had to explain for future fellas :)
Thank you @voytasify

Comment: Thank you! This response was everything I hoped for: simple, concise, to the point and illustrated!